# Is there a way to track an instance in Node without passing it around everywhere?

Tags: node.js

I have a singleton logger file. When a request comes into Express, I use middleware to set the request ID.

```
// Relevant parts of server.js
import express from 'express';
import requestIdMiddleware from './request-id-middleware';

const app = express();
app.use(requestIdMiddleware);
```

--

```
// Relevant parts of request-id-middleware.js
const uuid = require('uuid/v4');
const { setRequestId } = require('./logger');

module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  const id = uuid();
  req.id = id;
  // This sets a static variable on the plain logger object
  setRequestId(id);
  next();
};
```

--

```
// Relevant parts of logger.js
module.exports = {
  request_id: null,
  setRequestId: id => {
     this.request_id = id;
  },
  log: message => {
    // sends a log out using this.request_id, which is shared by all users of the server
  }
}
```

Using the plain object now means everyone is sharing the same value. So despite each request calling `setRequestId`, it means if the first request takes longer than the second, it may use the second request's ID when referencing logger's value.

It seems I would need to make the logger a class instead of a plain object, instantiate it in my request middleware, and then pass the instance through to ensure unique request IDs across multiple calls from same request.  Although unlikely, hoping to find a way around needing to pass a variable down into anything I want to log from.

Comment: Hm, tell me you don't edit the "logger" file on each request .. Because the words "When a request comes ... to set the request ID" sounds to me like "writing a request id to a file on each request". If you do, please consider memory db such as Redis and MongoDB. And if you don't need to save those, consider using simply a global variable ?

Comment: Please, don't describe the code, post it instead. For code-related questions, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is necessary.

Comment: Will update shortly :)